# Cannot read property 'vgN' of null in wiris editor

Tags: text-editor, mathjax, rich-text-editor

Cannot read property 'vgN' of null in wiriseditor.js at 7:21327

we are getting many issues which are recorded in TRACK.JS tool but we don't know whether users impacted or not?
please let us what's the root cause or solution.